# pointer issues in C++, not traversing correctly

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
    int main()
{
    const int x = 4;
    int row, col, j;
    int myArray[x][x], *xptr;


    for (row = 0; row < 4; row++){
        for (col = 0; col < 4; col++){
            myArray[row][col] = (row * 4) + col;
        }
    }

    printf("contents of myArray... \n");

    /* set xptr to the front of myArray*/
    xptr = &(myArray[0][0]);

    /*Print out the contents of the array. */
    for (row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            printf("%d ", *(xptr + (row * 4) + col));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* Print out contents again, this time increment the pointer. */
    printf(" Contents of the x array again... \n");

    /* Set xptr to the front of the x array. */

    xptr = &(myArray[0][0]);

    /*print out the contents of the array. */


        for (j = 0; j< 16; j++);

        printf("%d ", *xptr);

        xptr++;
    }
    }
```

I'm having trouble getting the array to reprint using the pointers as the print address. IE, according to my professors notes I should get 
Contents of the x array...

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Contents of the x array again...

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

but instead I get

```
contents of myArray...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
contents of the x array again...
0
```

and then it ends. I've tried playing with everything but I'm not sure whats giving me this error

thanks, 
Creecher

Comment: This is why proper code formatting can be crucial -- you should really try to make things match in terms of indentation to allow quick and easy spotting of mismatched braces etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (j = 0; j< 16; j++);
```

See that extra semicolon at the end of the line?

It also looks like your braces are not right, for this second loop.

Comment: oh boy, do i feel dumb :( thanks so much
i delted that extra semi colon, but im having trouble finding the bracket issue youre talking about? 

also, it printed out 

contents of myArray...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
contents of the x array again...
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: You will probably find the braces problem if you indent your code properly. This code's indentation is a horrible mess. It's all over the place. "int main()" is indented four spaces, for some reason; then, on the next line, the first left brace then inexplicably moved flush to the left margin. The last two lines in the shown code have closing braces, both at the same indentation level, etc... etc... etc... Most editors have a feature of automatically indenting the code correctly. Learn to use them.